# Authenticate user from browser and read cookie from command line

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, command-line

I need to create a command line where the first step is to authenticate the user before continuing with the next steps, for the authentication part, I would like to open a browser where the user can reuse an existing login page and self authenticate, meanwhile in the console app wait for a cookie to validate that the user has been logged in successfully before continuing with the next steps in the console.

Is there any framework of idea about how to implement this? this will need to be by a command line, using c#.

Answer (score 0):

You should run a simple local server in your cli program with a post route which ready to receive a token by request body.

Now you should request user to login through a specific url where you pass your local http server post route url as callback url.

Now from your browser's auth page if user logged in successfully then you should pass a token to the local cli's callback url by post method.

Then from your cli program you should call your api route for cookies to store them locally for future authentication from cli requests.

Now your cli program is successfully authenticated by the user.